# if condition not working as desired

Tags: vbscript

Writing a VB script to monitor battery percentage. If it is > 95, then unplug. If < 20, plug in charger or else hibernate and so on. When battery goes below 20%, there is a popup Plug-in charger… and though within 10 sec system is plugged, it goes to `else` part and hibernates. It does not enter "System won't hibernate" part.

`hibernate.bat` is a simple batch script to hibernate Windows7. 
The code is a never ending `for` loop, in which do while loop is used to replicate 'continue' in shell scripting. When battery reaches 20%, there is 10 sec time given to plugin charger. If charged, then it has to go to next for loop iteration. "If charged" loop is not being entered. Why?

```
Set oLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set oServices = oLocator.ConnectServer(".","root\wmi")
Set oResults = oServices.ExecQuery("select * from batteryfullchargedcapacity")
For Each oResult In oResults
    iFull = oResult.FullChargedCapacity
Next

For i=1 To 10
    Do
        i=+2
        Set oResults = oServices.ExecQuery("select * from batterystatus")
        For Each oResult In oResults
            iRemaining = oResult.RemainingCapacity
            Charging = oResult.Charging
            Discharging = oResult.Discharging
        Next

        iPercent = ((iRemaining / iFull) * 100) Mod 100
        If Charging And (iPercent > 95) Then
            MsgBox "Unplug Charger. Battery is at " & iPercent & "%", vbInformation, "Battery monitor"
        ElseIf Discharging And (iPercent < 20) Then
            MsgBox "Plug-in Charger. Battery is at " & iPercent & "%", vbInformation, "Battery monitor"
            WScript.Sleep 10000 ' 10 sec
            If Charging Then
                CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "System won't hibernate", 5, "Good News!!!"
                Exit Do
            Else
                Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
                shell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\Users\abcd\Desktop"
                CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "System will hibernate", 5, "Hmm..."
                shell.Run "hibernate.bat"
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Loop While False
Next
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Continue" (to next iteration) on VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944062/continue-to-next-iteration-on-vbscript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
ElseIf Discharging And (iPercent < 20) Then
    ...
    If Charging Then
        ...
    Else
        ...
    End If
End If
```

The `Charging` and `Discharging` state are the inverse of each other. If `Discharging` is true then `Charging` is false and vice versa. Because of this the value of `Charging` is *always* `False` when you enter the `ElseIf` branch. And since the value of the variable reflects the state at time of assignment it's *still* `False` even after you plug in a power cord. The variable doesn't automagically update itself when the battery state changes. You need to re-evaluate the battery state after the delay to make your code work as expected. For that I'd suggest refactoring the WMI lookup into two functions:

```
Function IsCharging
    For Each oResult In oServices.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM BatteryStatus")
        IsCharging = oResult.Charging
    Next
End Function

Function GetRemainingCapacity
    For Each oResult In oServices.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM BatteryStatus")
        GetRemainingCapacity = oResult.RemainingCapacity
    Next
End Function
```

and use them like this:

```
Do
    iPercent = ((GetRemainingCapacity / iFull) * 100) Mod 100
    If IsCharging And (iPercent > 95) Then
        ...
    ElseIf Not IsCharging And (iPercent < 20) Then
        ...
        If IsCharging Then
            ...
        Else
            ...
        End If
    End If
Loop While True
```