# Windows-10 battery indicator Visual Basic Script

Tags: windows, vbscript, windows-10

I got some code from the internet for a warning indicator. I use it for warning me when battery is charging and the battery level is above 80%.

But I also want to use it to warn me when the battery level is below 20%. I have added a line for this 20% warning, but it is not working. It works when battery is above 80%, but not when battery is below 20%.

I think the code is in Visual Basic Script (VBS).

Please help.

I have already searched on other forums and this one, but could not find such a program anywhere.

```
set oLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
set oServices = oLocator.ConnectServer(".","root\wmi")
set oResults = oServices.ExecQuery("select * from batteryfullchargedcapacity")
for each oResult in oResults
   iFull = oResult.FullChargedCapacity
next

while (1)
  set oResults = oServices.ExecQuery("select * from batterystatus")
  for each oResult in oResults
    iRemaining = oResult.RemainingCapacity
    bCharging = oResult.Charging
  next
  iPercent = ((iRemaining / iFull) * 100) mod 100
  if bCharging and (iPercent > 80) Then msgbox "Battery is charged now more than 80%. Please stop charging for optimal battery life."
  if bCharging and (iPercent < 20) Then msgbox "Battery is discharging and is below 20%. Please switch on charging immediately."
  wscript.sleep 30000 ' 5 minutes
wend
```

Comment: Why would you want a warning if the battery is charging and is below 20%? Or do you mean to test if the battery is **not** charging and is below 20%?

Comment: That's a good point. I only want to know when the battery is below 20% and when not being charged.

Comment: I guess that should read `if not bCharging and (iPercent < 20)` then

Comment: Works after a restart. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: My laptop seems to have 2 batteries. Is there a way to obtain the average of both batteries' charge, and whether or not one of them is charging?

The problem for me is that if battery 1 is at 40% and charging, and 2 is at 60% and not charging, then, instead of reporting that the battery is at 50% and charging, it reports 60% and not charging.

Answer (score 1):

If you need one that monitors 2 or more batteries in one laptop:

```
set oLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
set oServices = oLocator.ConnectServer(".","root\wmi")
set oResults = oServices.ExecQuery("select * from batteryfullchargedcapacity")
 
for each oResult in oResults
    iFull = oResult.FullChargedCapacity
next
 
while (1)
    set oResults = oServices.ExecQuery("select * from batterystatus")
    totalRemaining = 0
    batteryCount = 0
    for each oResult in oResults
        iRemaining = oResult.RemainingCapacity
        bCharging = oResult.Charging
        totalRemaining = totalRemaining + iRemaining
        batteryCount = batteryCount + 1
    next
    iPercent = Round(((totalRemaining / batteryCount) / iFull) * 100)
    
    if bCharging and (iPercent > 80) Then msgbox "Battery is charged now more than 80%. Please stop charging for optimal battery life."
    if not bCharging and (iPercent < 20) Then msgbox "Battery is discharging and is below 20%. Please switch on charging immediately."
  wscript.sleep 3000000 ' sleep for 5 minutes

wend
```

Comment: Very similar to [if condition not working as desired](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36979600)

Answer (score -2):

change - `if bCharging and (iPercent < 20)` to `if iRemaining and (iPercent < 20)`
because bCharging is While Plugged in
and iRemaining is While on Battery